# AWS ELB - SSL/TLS termination confusion

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, aws-elb

The setup: Application deployed in EC2 instances that are load balanced by an ELB, with Autoscaling Group.

The requirement: secure data encryption in transit in adherence to TLS protocol between the clients and EC2 instances.

The question:

1. How can you distinguish if a load balancer terminates TLS in itself or in the EC2 instances? I am preparing for the AWS Architect Associate exam and I have encountered this problem multiple times. It seems that whether it terminates TLS in itself or in EC2 instances, it uses port 443. If I have a set of multiple choice answers of possible ELB configurations, which one should I choose if I want TLS to be terminated at EC2 instance?
2. Is it different when it's a Network Load Balancer compared to a "regular" ELB?

Answer (score 2):

> How can you distinguish if a load balancer terminates TLS in itself or in the EC2s

If the Load Balancer terminates TLS, then it will have [HTTPS Listeners](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-https-load-balancers.html) with the cert associated with it.

> Is it different when its a Network Load Balancer? compared to a "regular" ELB.

Network Load Balancers are Level 4 load balancers and work at protocol level, handling TCP/UDP connections and till recently, did not have TLS offload. That has [changed now](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-tls-termination-for-network-load-balancers/) and the same principle holds - if there's a TLS listener, then it's mostly to be handling the TLS termination